# How to resolve ld-elf.so.1: /bin/sh: Undefined symbol "stat@FBSD_1.5" enter full pathname of shell or return for /bin/sh:

Tags: freebsd

In my upgrade from freebsd 11 to FreeBSD 12 I got an error message

 `ld-elf.so.1: /bin/sh: Undefined symbol "stat@FBSD_1.5"`

I restarted my OS and now error continued

 `ld-elf.so.1: /bin/sh: Undefined symbol "stat@FBSD_1.5"
enter full pathname of shell or return for /bin/sh:`

and when I want to type any command I see this message

`cannot execute COMMAND for single user: no such file or directory`

Of course, I started my FreeBSD with multiple user mode, but this message appears when I want to use Enter key for any written command, How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with this command

```
/rescue/sh
```

special thanks to [yuripv](https://forums.freebsd.org/members/yuripv.55651/) in:
https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/how-to-resolve-ld-elf-so-1-bin-sh-undefined-symbol-stat-fbsd_1-5-enter-full-pathname-of-shell-or-return-for-bin-sh.72611/

Of course, this can only open a way to work with terminal after reboot system, but I cannot find a way to resolve this error message

`ld-elf.so.1: /bin/sh: Undefined symbol "stat@FBSD_1.5"`

this error message appears when I send any command via terminal